# Should a 502 HTTP status code be used if a proxy receives no response at all?

Tags: http, client, http-status-codes, status

According to the RFC:

> **10.5.3 502 Bad Gateway**
>   The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server it accessed in attempting to fulfill the request.

Can *invalid response* also mean no response at all (e.g. connection refused)?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Yes. Empty or incomplete headers or response body typically caused by broken connections or server side crash can cause 502 errors if accessed via a gateway or proxy.

For more information about the network errors

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: my request body format was mismatched after fixing the format ti worked for me.

Comment: When request body is wrong it should throw 400 not 500.