# Forex-python "Currency Rates Source Not Ready"

Tags: python, pandas, currency

I want to use the Forex-python module to convert amounts in various currencies to a specific currency ("DKK") according to a specific date (The last day of a previous month according to a date in the dataframe)

This is the structure of my code:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={'Date':['2017-4-15','2017-6-12','2017-2-25'],'Amount':[5,10,15],'Currency':['USD','SEK','EUR']})

def convert_rates(amount,currency,PstngDate):
    PstngDate = datetime.strptime(PstngDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
    if currency != 'DKK':
        return c.convert(base_cur=currency,dest_cur='DKK',amount=amount \
                     ,date_obj=PstngDate - timedelta(PstngDate.day))
    else:
        return amount
```

and the the new column with the converted amount:

```
df['Amount, DKK'] = np.vectorize(convert_rates)(
    amount=df['Amount'],
    currency=df['Currency'],
    PstngDate=df['Date']
)
```

I get the RatesNotAvailableError "Currency Rates Source Not Ready"
Any idea what can cause this? It has previously worked with small amounts of data, but I have many rows in my real df...

Comment: what library is `c.convert()` calling? If it's calling some external source, it's possible that you're being rate limited because `np.vectorize` is calling too frequently. Check the docs for whatever `c` is, then perhaps you might need to do the lookups serially.

Comment: Ah, sorry: It's calling the forex-python library - Do you know how I can get around the limitation?

Comment: https://github.com/MicroPyramid/forex-python/blob/80290a2b9150515e15139e1a069f74d220c6b67e/forex_python/converter.py#L73  Looks like the library doesn't talk about quotas. Your error just suggests the source returned a non 200 response code. Suggest instead doing the calculation serially, with a retry function and some kind of backoff

Answer (score 1):

I inserted a small print statement into convert.py (part of forex-python) to debug this.

```
print(response.status_code)
```

Currently I receive:

```
502
```

Read these threads about the HTTP 502 error:

[In HTTP 502, what is meant by an invalid response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660464/in-http-502-what-is-meant-by-an-invalid-response)

https://www.lifewire.com/502-bad-gateway-error-explained-2622939

> These errors are completely independent of your particular setup,
> meaning that you could see one in any browser, on any operating
> system, and on any device.

502 indicates that currently there is a problem with the infrastructure this API uses to provide us with the required data. As I am in need of the data myself I will continue to monitor this issue and keep my post on this site updated.

There is already an issue on Github regarding this issue:

https://github.com/MicroPyramid/forex-python/issues/100

Comment: Update: The issue was fixed and the error does no longer occur.

Answer (score 1):

I've made an API for exchange rates (got a bit frustrated changing packages every now and then as they stopped working and depend on others):

https://exchange.nanoapi.dev

You don't need to install any 3rd party dependencies and I included examples how to use it in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

From the source: https://github.com/MicroPyramid/forex-python/blob/80290a2b9150515e15139e1a069f74d220c6b67e/forex_python/converter.py#L73

Your error means the library received a non 200 response code to your request. This could mean the site is down, or it's blocked you momentarily because you're hammering it with requests.

Try replacing the call to `c.convert` with something like:

```
from time import sleep
def try_convert(amount, currency, PstngDate):
    success = False
    while success == False:
        try:
            res = c.convert(base_cur=currency,dest_cur='DKK',amount=amount \
                     ,date_obj=PstngDate - timedelta(PstngDate.day))
        except:
            #wait a while
            sleep(10)
    return res
```

Or even better, use a library like backoff, to do the retrying for you:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backoff/1.3.1

Comment: Thank you, I encounter the same error but the point is: How to find out the API limits? Of course I could use backoff but what are the conditions that need to be met?

Comment: This would really be down to the API. Presumably it would have documentation somewhere mentioning any rate limiting conditions?

Comment: Presumably yes...